# Entity Framework 6: Skip() & Take() do not generate SQL, instead the result set is filtered after loading into memory. Or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, profiler

I have the following code that should gets some `book`, and retrieve the first 2  `tag`s (`Tag` entities) from that book (`Book` entity).
So `Tags` is a `navigation property` of the `Book` entity.

```
using (var context = new FakeEndavaBookLibraryEntities())
{
      Book firstBook = context.Set<Book>().Take(1).First();
      var firstTwoTags = firstBook.Tags.OrderBy(tag => tag.Id).Skip(0).Take(2).ToList();
}
```

I **expect** obtaining the following SQL query that has to be generated by EF.

```
SELECT TOP(2)
       [Extent2].[Id]      AS [Id],
       [Extent2].[Version] AS [Version],
       [Extent2].[Name]    AS [Name]
FROM   [Literature].[BookTagRelation] AS [Extent1]
       INNER JOIN [Literature].[Tag] AS [Extent2]
         ON [Extent1].[TagId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE  [Extent1].[BookId] = 1 /* @EntityKeyValue1 - [BookId] */
```

Instead, the EF Profiler shows me that the EF is generating **unbounded result set** (like **SELECT * FROM ..**.)

```
SELECT [Extent2].[Id]      AS [Id],
       [Extent2].[Version] AS [Version],
       [Extent2].[Name]    AS [Name]
FROM   [Literature].[BookTagRelation] AS [Extent1]
       INNER JOIN [Literature].[Tag] AS [Extent2]
         ON [Extent1].[TagId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE  [Extent1].[BookId] = 1 /* @EntityKeyValue1 - [BookId] */
```

[Here is a scheme fragment if you need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQVpC.jpg)

I also **tried to append** the `.AsQueryable()` to `firstBook.Tags` property and/or remove `.Skip(0)` method as is shown below, but **this didn't help** as well.

```
      var firstTwoTags = firstBook.Tags.AsQueryable().OrderBy(tag => tag.Id).Skip(0).Take(2).ToList();
```

The same undesired behavior:

```
SELECT [Extent2].[Id]      AS [Id],
       [Extent2].[Version] AS [Version],
       [Extent2].[Name]    AS [Name]
FROM   [Literature].[BookTagRelation] AS [Extent1]
       INNER JOIN [Literature].[Tag] AS [Extent2]
         ON [Extent1].[TagId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE  [Extent1].[BookId] = 1 /* @EntityKeyValue1 - [BookId] */
```

---

**Have you ever encountered** the same problem when working with Entity Framework 6?

**Are there any workarounds** to overcome this problem or I've designed the query in a wrong way...?

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: Why are you using Skip, Take, AND SingleOrDefault?. If you do not care about the number of Tags, just replace Skip().Take().SingleOrDefault() with .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @SebastianBrand To be honest I'm planning to do pagination... by `Skip(toBeSkipped).Take(pageSize)`. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @[hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) pointed out, I had to work with `IQueryable<Tag>`, whereas `firstBook.Tags` *navigation property* is just a lazy-loaded `IEnumerable<Tag>`.
So here is the solution of my problem, based on the @[hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd)'s answer.

```
Tag firstTag = context.Set<Tag>() // or even context.Tags
    .Where(tag => tag.Books.Any(book => book.Id == firstBook.Id))
    .OrderBy(tag => tag.Id)
    .Skip(0).Take(1)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

So the minor changes of @[hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd)'s solution are: **replacing** the

`.Where(tag => tag.Books.Contains(firstBook))` with

> Something that EF understands

1) `.Where(tag => tag.Books.Any(book => book.Id == firstBook.Id))`.

or

2) `.Where(tag => tag.Books.Select(book => book.Id).Contains(firstBook.Id))`

Any sequence of code (1) or (2) generates the following SQL query, which is definitely **no longer** an **unbounded result set**.

```
SELECT [Project2].[Id]      AS [Id],
       [Project2].[Version] AS [Version],
       [Project2].[Name]    AS [Name]
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id]      AS [Id],
               [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version],
               [Extent1].[Name]    AS [Name]
        FROM   [Literature].[Tag] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                       FROM   [Literature].[BookTagRelation] AS [Extent2]
                       WHERE  ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[TagId])
                              AND ([Extent2].[BookId] = 1 /* @p__linq__0 */))) AS [Project2]
ORDER  BY [Project2].[Id] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 6):

`firstBook.Tags` is a lazily-loaded `IEnumerable<Tag>`. On the first access, all tags are loaded, and subsequent attempts to turn it into an `IQueryable<Tag>` do not work, since you did not start from something from which you could sensibly query.

Instead, start from a known good `IQueryable<Tag>`. Something along the lines of

```
Tag firstTag = context.Set<Tag>()
    .Where(tag => tag.Books.Contains(firstBook))
    .OrderBy(tag => tag.Id).Skip(0).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

should work. You might need minor tweaking to turn the filter condition into something EF understands.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. I had to do some minor changes to your solution in order to make it work. When I ran your code (**As is**) I got the following exception `Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Repositories.Implementation.Book'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context`. But after **replacing** the
`.Where(tag => tag.Books.Contains(firstBook))` with `.Where(tag => tag.Books.Any(book => book.Id == firstBook.Id))` **I obtained the SQL query I was trying to construct** using *LINQ to SQL*.

Comment: @Andrey-WD My second thought would have been `.Where(tag => tag.Books.Select(book => book.Id).Contains(firstBook.Id))`, but your query looks correct as well. Glad you got it working.